# why cors issue coming even though angular application running on the same server from where we are calling the rest call

Tags: angularjs, cors

I have developed angular application in my local machine.
In my application I'm making the rest call to get the data.
So in my local machine I'm getting the CORS issue.
But when I deploy this angular application on the same server with same port
i.e. both rest api and my application are on same server with same port.
REST API:- http://domain:port/api 
App URL:- http://domain:port/home

Then also I'm getting the CORS issue while making the call to rest api.
Please explain me how to resolve this.

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: Can you share how are you setting up rest api and angular app on the same server, plus how're you calling rest api from angular app

Comment: Rest api was developed by some other team mates in java and they deployed on the server. And Angular application was developed by us in local machine and generated the build using "npm build --aot" and pasted the dist folder in the  same location where our rest api was deployed. This what we did.

Comment: One thing you might want to check is what url you're using to communicate with the rest API. If it starts with something like  https://someurl/api/users try just /api/users, (removing prefix i.e https://someurl) if angular app is not able to communicate with just /api/url then this means they're not on the same origin. Finally you may need to allow cross origin access from java side of things

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52940757/edit to edit/update the question & add the exact error message the browser’s logging in the devtools console. *“I'm getting the CORS issue”* isn’t enough info at all for anybody to guess what the actual problem might be. But If your `http://domain:port/home` app is making a request to `http://domain:port/api` that’s actually on the same origin (scheme+host+port), then you’re not gonna have a CORS error. So either the problem is, your app is calling some other server at a different origin, or whatever problem you’re having isn’t a CORS problem

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine you can create a proxy to redirect calls to the api to be on the same port as your angular app. Create a file called proxy.conf.json and put the following in it changing apiport to your apis port number.

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:apiport/api/",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and then start the app with

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

or add the following to the scripts section of your package.json file

```
"localstart": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
```

and start with

```
npm run localstart
```

Comment: I'm using the proxy only to avoid cors issue. But my question is why I'm still getting the CORS issue even though my application and rest api are running on the same server (same domain and same port). i.e. if I remove the proxy I'm not able to get the data from rest call.

Comment: Are you getting the CORS issue when you run from the server with the http://domain:port/home or just when you are testing from http://localhost:5200? If it is when you are testing it is because http://localhost:5200 is not on the same domain as http://domain:port/api

Comment: I'm getting the CORS issue when I run from the server if I remove the proxy.

Comment: The proxy doesn't run on the server, it is a local dev concept only

Comment: how can I check whether my proxy is used in the server or not? While generating the build do I need to specify any thing to not consider the proxy? Or simply do I need to remove the options from ""start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json" this command in package.json file.

Comment: The proxy has nothing to do with your build, when you build and deploy to the server there is no proxy involved. The proxy is only for when you are running on the local dev server so you can reroute the api calls to the local dev servers domain and port. Once you build you need to host the Angular app and the api on the same domain and port.